# Show chat history with asmack in android

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am developing an android chat client app and I'm using asmack for XMPP implementation. I was able to make connection to my XMPP server and was able to make send chat messages. I need to show chat history for a specific user in my app. How can I do that?

I tried to retrieve it using following code:

```
PubSubManager mgr = new PubSubManager(con);
LeafNode node = mgr.getNode("mynode");
Collection<? extends Item> items = node.getItems();
```

but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do this with asmack??

Comment: Certainly not by using pubsub, which has nothing to do with chat.

Comment: Finally found the answer. I need to subscribe to the user for which I had to fetch chat history. So adding node.subscribe(jid) did the trick

Comment: @althaf_tvm can you please write your comment as a answer and make it clear.